# Marking forwarded third party messages as spam in Gmail without marking the forwarder as Spam

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, spam-prevention, outlook-web-access

I have an Outlook web account that forwards emails to a Gmail account.

The Outlook account uses a redirect mail rule to redirect messages sent to the Outlook account to the Gmail account so the email comes "from" the original sender, but it shows up as "mailed-by" my outlook domain.

For instance, when a forwarded email is received in the Gmail inbox, the sending information is as follows:

```
from:       Original Sender Name <originalsender@originalsenderdomain.com>
to:         myoutlookaccount@mydomain.com
date:       Jul 6, 2023, 8:11 PM
subject:    subject
mailed-by:  myoutlookdomain.com
signed-by:  originalsenderdomain.com
security:   Standard encryption (TLS) Learn more
```

The Outlook account receives a lot of spam which is forwarded to the Gmail account.

If I mark that email as spam in Gmail, will it mark my Outlook account as spam or the third party originally sending the email?

Comment: Likely, the last address, i.e., the Outlook account, would be considered the spammer. Rather than marking a message as spam, you might create a GMail filter to send mail to Trash for all messages meeting certain criteria, e.g., from a specific sender, or having specific words in subject. Yes, that is more work.

Comment: It really depends who you see as a sender in GMAIL. If you see the original sender, then you can mark directly as spam. If you see your outlook account as sender, you should (if possible) change the settings in outlook so as to achieve a direct forward.

Comment: Being a long time mail server administrator I'd say it's **fair** to mark forwarder itself as a spam if it really forwards spam. Such a "too simple" forwarder can be abused too much easily and that will become annoying and the only way to get rid with that annoyance is to get rid of faulty forwarder. Don't forward spam if you don't want to be a spammer yourself. Forwarders are "necessary evil", do without them if you can; for example, instead of forwarding from A to B at SMTP level consider setting up a service at B which will pull mails from A via e.g. POP3 or something like that.

Comment: You should be reporting the spam at the Outlook account side of things.

Answer (score 0):

> If I mark that email as spam in Gmail, will it mark my Outlook account as spam or the third party originally sending the email?

Not necessarily.

When you mark an email as spam, Google will receive a copy of the email and may analyze it to help protect our users from spam and abuse. See [this link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1366858). However, this doesn't mean that the sender of this email would be added to the block list.

If you continuously reported these mails as spam and led to the sender marked as spam by gmail, it depends on how you set up the email forwarding. If it's set up by yourself using the inbox rule, it's likely that the outlook account would be marked as spam because this is the actual sender seen by gmail.